# Mercurial - Showing what files has been modified during update?

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a way to watch if a file has been changed during update.
On way would be for example an additional command to `hg update` to show files that has been modified.

Comment: and by modified I mean modified, removed, added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't `hg update -v` do what you want?